# USB Modem Repeatedly Connects and Disconnects

Tags: boot, networking, usb, usb-modem, 3g

Description:
I am experiencing an issue with my USB modem where it repeatedly connects and disconnects. The device is an Alcatel USB modem, and I noticed that it undergoes multiple connection and disconnection cycles, sometimes changing its device name during these events. This issue leads to inconsistent connectivity and interrupts the functionality of the modem.

The system's dmesg log shows a continuous loop of messages indicating USB device connection, disconnection, and renaming. I have observed these sequences where the modem connects, disconnects, and changes its name multiple times within a short duration.

This behavior occurs despite a stable physical connection and seems to be independent of any specific software or action. I have tried troubleshooting by checking the physical connections, updating relevant drivers, and examining the system's logs without finding a resolution.

I would appreciate any insights, suggestions, or potential solutions to address this repetitive connecting and disconnecting issue with my USB modem.

```
[76860.193896] usb 1-3.7.1: new high-speed USB device number 21 using xhci_hcd
[76860.419478] usb 1-3.7.1: New USB device found, idVendor=1bbb, idProduct=f000, bcdDevice=10.00
[76860.419497] usb 1-3.7.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[76860.419508] usb 1-3.7.1: Product: Mobilebroadband
[76860.419515] usb 1-3.7.1: Manufacturer: Alcatel
[76860.419523] usb 1-3.7.1: SerialNumber: 1234567890ABCDE
[76860.429743] usb-storage 1-3.7.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[76860.445645] scsi host4: usb-storage 1-3.7.1:1.0
[76861.408374] usb 1-3.7.1: USB disconnect, device number 21
[76862.501896] usb 1-3.7.1: new high-speed USB device number 22 using xhci_hcd
[76862.731520] usb 1-3.7.1: New USB device found, idVendor=1bbb, idProduct=0191, bcdDevice= 2.42
[76862.731536] usb 1-3.7.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[76862.731543] usb 1-3.7.1: Product: Mobilebroadband
[76862.731549] usb 1-3.7.1: Manufacturer: Alcatel
[76862.731554] usb 1-3.7.1: SerialNumber: 1234567890ABCDE
[76862.750244] cdc_ether 1-3.7.1:1.0 usb0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-3.7.1, CDC Ethernet Device, aa:ba:4d:75:05:96
[76862.954262] cdc_ether 1-3.7.1:1.0 modem1902: renamed from usb0
[78323.168275] usb 1-3.7.1: USB disconnect, device number 22
[78323.168435] cdc_ether 1-3.7.1:1.0 modem1902: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-0000:00:14.0-3.7.1, CDC Ethernet Device
```